# Oracle SQL: Divided one row to other row in other table without repatriation depending in variable value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have tow table :

**Customer** :

```
name
-----
TOMMY 
LOUIE 
HUGO 
OLLIE 
DAVID 
LEWIS 
JACKSON
```

**Employees** :

```
name     | stage
---------+---------
OLIVER   |  1
NOAH     |  1
ALFIE    |  1
OSCAR    |  2
NOAH     |  2
OLIVER   |  2
LEO      |  2
```

In Employee I have two stages. In each stage can it have same employees or different, what I want to divide or distribute the customer to employee with two condition :

1. the customer in first stage **must** have different employee in second stage
2. each employee must have same number of customer in each stage and each customer must have 1 employee in each stage without repetition.

I have done the procedure with cursor that insert the result in different table but the problem it give wrong result that repeating the customer in stage 1 to the same employee in stage 2 (e.g NOAH take the same Customer )

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE AUDIT_Customer   AS

CURSOR Customer_STAGE1 IS SELECT * FROM (
                select
                      s.name  Customer_name
                      ,t.name Employees_name 
                from (select name, row_number() over(order by name) as rn from Employees  WHERE stage = 1 ) t
                join (select name, row_number() over(order by name) as rn from Customer  ) s
                on mod(s.rn - 1, (select count(*) from Employees WHERE stage = 1)) = t.rn -1); 


CURSOR Customer_STAGE2 IS SELECT * FROM (
                select
                      s.name  Customer_name
                      ,t.name Employees_name 
                from (select name, row_number() over(order by name) as rn from Employees  WHERE stage = 2 ) t
                join (select name, row_number() over(order by name) as rn from Customer   ) s
                on mod(s.rn - 1, (select count(*) from Employees WHERE stage = 2)) = t.rn -1);                 


Begin 
      For y in  Customer_STAGE1 Loop

             Insert  into Customer_Employee(Customer_name,Employees_name,RECIVE_DATE,stage)
             Values  (Y.Customer_name ,Y.Employees_name,sysdate,1) ;

      End Loop ;

       For y in  Customer_STAGE2 Loop

             Insert  into Customer_Employee(Customer_name,Employees_name,RECIVE_DATE,stage)
             Values  (Y.Customer_name ,Y.Employees_name,sysdate,2) ;

      End Loop ;


   COMMIT;               
End AUDIT_Customer;
```

**the results :**

```
    Customer| Employees| stage
    --------+--------- +---------
    TOMMY   | OLIVER   |  1
    LOUIE   | OLIVER   |  1
    HUGO    | NOAH     |  1
    OLLIE   | NOAH     |  1
    DAVID   | ALFIE    |  1
    LEWIS   | ALFIE    |  1
    JACKSON | ALFIE    |  1
    TOMMY   | OSCAR    |  2
    LOUIE   | OSCAR    |  2
    HUGO    | NOAH     |  2
    OLLIE   | NOAH     |  2
    DAVID   | OLIVER   |  2
    LEWIS   | OLIVER   |  2
    JACKSON | LEO      |  2
```

how i can solve it?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: using Oracle sql

Answer (score 0):

filter the second section of your procedure 
this might help:

```
(select name, row_number() over(order by name) as rn from Employees  WHERE stage = 2 and Employee.Name not in (select Employee.Name from Employee WHERE stage = 1))
```

Comment: its not work .. its ignore the employees how is in both stage 1 and 2 ( e.g. NOAH ).